# How to use numpy lexsort on a 3d array without changing the shape on the resulting array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3d array like so:

```
arr = [
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]],
[[1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3]]
]
```

I'd like to sort the inner arrays inside the second dimension array using the last item in that length 3 array as the first sorting column, then the second item, then the first item.

So the result should be:

```
arr = [
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1]],
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]],
[[2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 2], [1, 0, 3]]
]
```

The way I am attempting to do this is as follows:

```
arr = [
    [[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]],
    [[1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3]]
]

sort = (arr[:, 2], arr[:, 1], arr[:, 0])
arr = arr[np.lexsort(sort)]

print(arr)
```

But it changes the array shape from (3,3,3) to (3,3,3,3) and the result is as follows:

```
[[[[1 2 2]
   [2 0 0]
   [1 0 3]]
  [[1 2 0]
   [1 0 1]
   [1 0 0]]
  [[1 2 1]
   [1 0 2]
   [1 2 0]]]
 [[[1 2 0]
   [1 0 1]
   [1 0 0]]
  [[1 2 2]
   [2 0 0]
   [1 0 3]]
  [[1 2 1]
   [1 0 2]
   [1 2 0]]]
 [[[1 2 0]
   [1 0 1]
   [1 0 0]]
  [[1 2 1]
   [1 0 2]
   [1 2 0]]
  [[1 2 2]
   [2 0 0]
   [1 0 3]]]]
```

I tried

```
sort = (arr[:, :, 2], arr[:, :, 1], arr[:, :, 0])
arr = arr[np.lexsort(sort)]
```

But it also changes the shape to (3,3,3,3)

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get it working like this:

```
arr = np.array([
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]],
[[1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3]]
])

for i in range(len(arr)):
    item = arr[i]
    arr[i] = item[np.lexsort((item[:, 0], item[:, 1], item[:, 2]))]

print(arr)
```

But having a loop like this doesn't seem great - my actual arrays are very, very large. About 80Gb of memory large. If anyone can help me get the correct single call to numpy to get this right I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broke my head over it for a solid hour, and after mostly playing around, I'm convinced the following works:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]],
    [[1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3]]
])

idx = np.lexsort(arr.T, axis=0)
out = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None], idx.T, :]
```

but I can't exactly explain how :). If the ordering isn't simply reverse order (col 2, col 1, col 0), then I'll need to play around with it a bit more...

out:

```
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[1, 2, 0],
        [1, 2, 1],
        [1, 0, 2]],

       [[2, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 2],
        [1, 0, 3]]])
```

Comment: Dude, what kind of voodoo is this?! haha I don't know why it works either, but it does. I tested with a set of 448 million rows, each composed of 3 arrays like the ones you worked with. My method took 166137ms, yours took 18799ms - almost 10x faster! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This would work simply actually (my apologies for previous mistake):

```
arr = np.array([
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0]],
[[1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3]]
])

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    arr[i] = np.vstack((arr[i][2, :], arr[i][0, :], arr[i][1, :]))
```

Comment: Not sure why but it seems it is not actually changing the arr. The last row for example, should be `[[2, 0, 0], [1, 2, 2], [1, 0, 3]]`, but the code still returns `[[1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 3]]` - any ideas?

Comment: Hey @EdyBourne sorry for mistake moveaxis changes the axis. vstack would do the job.